# SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in Oracle Update query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK table in which i have saved sql in CHECK_SQL column. This column is Varchar data type. Now i want to update particular sql.I have written below update sql query but it gives an error `SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`. I also tried to query with double quote but then it gives an error as  `SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long`.

```
    Update RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK SET CHECK_SQL = 'select count(*) as CNT from O2_SDR_Header
where id = (select max(id) from O2_SDR_Header where id > 2012000000000000 and sp_id = 'SP602') 
And sp_id = 'SP602' and FILE_CREATED_DATE > (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' HOUR)'
WHERE SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK_ID = 604;
```

Comment: String literals need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL. Please read the manual (the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should be like this : `sp_id = 'SP602'` to `sp_id = ''SP602''`

and this `'2'` to `''2''`

your final code should be like this

```
 Update RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK SET CHECK_SQL = 'select count(*) as CNT from O2_SDR_Header
where id = (select max(id) from O2_SDR_Header where id > 2012000000000000 and sp_id = ''SP602'') 
And sp_id = ''SP602'' and FILE_CREATED_DATE > (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL ''2'' HOUR)'
WHERE SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK_ID = 604;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to escape you single quote, as below

```
Update RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK SET CHECK_SQL = "select count(*) as CNT from O2_SDR_Header
where id = (select max(id) from O2_SDR_Header where id > 2012000000000000 and sp_id = ''SP602'') 
And sp_id = ''SP602'' and FILE_CREATED_DATE > (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '2' HOUR)"
WHERE SYSTEM_SQL_CHECK_ID = 604;
```

Comment: As i mentioned in my query when i tried to use double quote i am getting an error as SQL Error: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: @Rahul - it isn't a double-quote (`"`) around the text literals, it's two single quotes (`'''`). Very different. Also consider [the alternative quoting mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218) for text literals. You need to escape the quotes around the '2' interval value too.

Comment: Ohh sorry Alex but i tried the above query also and it gives me the same identifier error.

Comment: @Rahul the 2 should be fixed also add ''2''

Comment: This is still wrong. The _whole_ literal needs to be put in single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: Yes @a_horse_with_no_name you are right its working now